# Images resizing in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone telle me how to reduce the size of the image in the slider on this page:

http://www.lgm-television.com/

the code is here:

http://www.lgm-television.com/wp-content/themes/immersion/js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js?ver=3.4.2

Comment: Your first link asks username and password

Comment: we cant see lgm, it needs login

Comment: You could only change the height and width of the image, but as the image would just stay the same binary, you would only get a sub optimal result of a downsized images that still uses the same bandwidth.

Comment: Only way to reduce the size of the images is 2 things, either enable gzip compression on the server or/and on the server side with some server side language resize the image before outputting it

Answer (score 0):

Only ways to reduce the size of images on the fly to save bandwidth im guessing are 2 ways, either enable gzip compression on the server or/and on the server side with some server side language resize the image before outputting it. There are great many scripts out there, if you're used to php for example which is a great beginner language for webdevelopers(why? you might askw well that is another story for another question) you can find great many ready to use script on [google](https://www.google.se/#hl=sv&sclient=psy-ab&q=resize+image+php&oq=resize+image) or [PHPclasses](http://www.phpclasses.org/)